# Cisco asa 5505 - can't browse locally hosted website by using it's domain name

Tags: dns, domain, hosting

I have the following:
- Domain with DNS record set to my Public IP
- Public IP, via Comcast Modem/Router Sending all web traffic to the Web Server (1st Network Card)
- I also Have Cisco ASA5505 after Modem and all internal network sits behind it
- When I try to open my site from local network, it does nto work- I can browse it y IP only. But it works from outsite my local network.

Maybe Cisco blocks someting? like some DNS requests? I don't know. Need help of the expert!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. On your computer open Network Connections.
2. Right-click on Local Area Connection and select Properties.
3. Click Internet Protocol Version 4 line.
4. Select Properties.
5. I'm using 192.168.1.100 (the local address my router forwards port 80 to)
6. Click the Advanced button.
7. Click the Add button and enter the public address (the number displayed by WhatsMyIP)

Save and you're ready to connect via localhost or www.myname.com

Comment: it did not help